# Angular Material: mat-tree does not consider the children of a list obtained through an @Input

Tags: angular, angular-material, nested, treeview, parent-child

I'm implementing this ['@angular/material' example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-nested-overview). The problem is that when sending the list of data from a parent component, the nesting in the '.html' is not implemented.

Example:

If I copy the list of objects and put it as a constant in the 'component.ts' (`const comments: Comments[] = ['All data']`) I get the nesting correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTDRO.png)

But if I try to get the list of objects from an '@Input' I get the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dap8K.png)

---

This is my code:

comment.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-comment',
    templateUrl: './comment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comment.component.css'],
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() comments!: Comments[];

    treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Comments>(node => node.children);
    dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Comments>();

    hasChild = (_: number, node: Comments) =>
        !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.data = this.comments;
    }
}
```

comment.interface.ts

```
export interface Comments {
    by: String;
    id: number;
    parent: number;
    text: String;
    time: number;
    deleted?: boolean;
    dead?: boolean;
    kids?: number[];
    children?: Comments[];
    type: string;
}
```

I'm trying to display a list of comments containing, in each instance itself, a sublist of comments.

I pass the list of comments to a 'mat-tree' component of '@angular/material' to display the parent comments and then extend to the child comments.

The problem is that even if the data is sent correctly, the 'mat-tree' component does not recognize the nesting and only shows the parent comments.

Comment: Could you show how you give data from @Input. It should look like <app-comment [comments]="['All data']">

Comment: ```<div class="main-body">
    <div *ngIf="!comments; else divTabla" class="alert alert-info">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <ng-template #divTabla>
        <app-story [story]="story"></app-story>
        <app-comment [comments]="comments"></app-comment>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qwokq?file=src/main.ts Is this what you expected?